# Unable to install pylint-flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pylint

I am attempting to add pylint-flask-sqlalchemy to my python pipenv virtual environment and am getting an exception

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 100, in __init__
    raise InvalidRequirement(
pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Parse error at "'-otocore'": Expected W:(abcd...)
```

This causes other dependencies to not be installed.

Here is my Pipfile

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[packages]
Werkzeug = "<1.0"
#"0.16.1"
flask = "*"
flask-cors = "*"
flask-restplus = "*"
boto3 = "*"
bcrypt = "*"
flask-jwt-extended = "*"
certifi = "*"
flask-sqlalchemy = "*"
flask-apscheduler = "*"
flask-migrate = "*"
coverage = "*"
pymysql = "*"
deep-security-api = "*"
sqlparse = "*"
importlib-metadata = "*"
requests = "*"
xmltodict = "*"
apscheduler = "*"
tornado = "==5.1.1"
python-dateutil = "*"
sqlalchemy = "*"
elasticsearch = "*"
requests-aws4auth = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
gevent = "*"
python3-saml = "*"
xmlsec = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"

[dev-packages]
autopep8 = "*"
pylint = "*"
pytest-flask = "*"
moto = "*"
pytest = "*"
black = "*"
atomicwrites = "*"
pre-commit = "*"
pytest-cov = "*"
pytest-mock = "*"
pylint-flask-sqlalchemy = "*"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```

This is the output

```
paul-> pipenv install pylint-flask-sqlalchemy --dev --verbose
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Installing pylint-flask-sqlalchemy…
Installing package: pylint-flask-sqlalchemy
Writing supplied requirement line to temporary file: 'pylint-flask-sqlalchemy'
Installing 'pylint-flask-sqlalchemy'
⠸ Installing pylint-flask-sqlalchemy...$ ['/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/bin/pip', 'install', '--pre', '--verbose', '--upgrade', '--exists-action=i', '-r', '/var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv-d1vqrymu-requirements/pipenv-yesf68j2-requirement.txt', '-i', 'https://pypi.org/simple']
Adding pylint-flask-sqlalchemy to Pipfile's [dev-packages]…
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock (8defad) out of date, updating to (01e0db)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
⠙ Locking...
                          ROUND 1                           


[snipped to lower StackOverflow character count]

                          ROUND 4                           
Current constraints:
  appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 (from black==20.8b1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 5))
  astroid<2.6,>=2.5.1 (from pylint==2.7.2->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 8))
  atomicwrites (from -r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 7))
  attrs>=19.2.0 (from pytest==6.2.2->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 10))
  autopep8 (from -r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 12))
  black (from -r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 5))
  boto3>=1.9.201 (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  botocore<1.21.0,<2.0a.0,>=1.12.201,>=1.12.36,>=1.20.19 (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests==2.25.1->moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  cffi>=1.12 (from cryptography==3.4.6->moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  cfgv>=2.0.0 (from pre-commit==2.10.1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 2))
  chardet<5,>=3.0.2 (from requests==2.25.1->moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  click>=5.1,>=7.1.2 (from black==20.8b1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 5))
  coverage>=5.2.1 (from pytest-cov==2.11.1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 3))
  cryptography>=3.3.1 (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  distlib<1,>=0.3.1 (from virtualenv==20.4.2->pre-commit==2.10.1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 2))
  filelock<4,>=3.0.0 (from virtualenv==20.4.2->pre-commit==2.10.1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 2))
  flask>=0.10 (from pytest-flask==1.2.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 11))
  flask-sqlalchemy>=2 (from pylint-flask-sqlalchemy==0.2.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 6))
  identify>=1.0.0 (from pre-commit==2.10.1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 2))
  idna<3,>=2.5 (from requests==2.25.1->moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  iniconfig (from pytest==6.2.2->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 10))
  isort<6,>=4.2.5 (from pylint==2.7.2->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 8))
  itsdangerous>=0.24 (from flask==1.1.2->pytest-flask==1.2.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 11))
  jinja2>=2.10.1 (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from boto3==1.17.19->moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  lazy-object-proxy>=1.4.0 (from astroid==2.5.1->pylint==2.7.2->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 8))
  markupsafe<2.0,>=0.23 (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  mccabe<0.7,>=0.6 (from pylint==2.7.2->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 8))
  mock (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  more-itertools (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  moto (from -r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  mypy-extensions>=0.4.3 (from black==20.8b1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 5))
  nodeenv>=0.11.1 (from pre-commit==2.10.1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 2))
  packaging (from pytest==6.2.2->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 10))
  pathspec<1,>=0.6 (from black==20.8b1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 5))
  pluggy<1.0.0a1,>=0.12 (from pytest==6.2.2->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 10))
  pre-commit (from -r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 2))
  py>=1.8.2 (from pytest==6.2.2->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 10))
  pycodestyle>=2.6.0 (from autopep8==1.5.5->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 12))
  pycparser (from cffi==1.14.5->cryptography==3.4.6->moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  pylint (from -r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 8))
  pylint-flask-sqlalchemy (from -r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 6))
  pyparsing>=2.0.2 (from packaging==20.9->pytest==6.2.2->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 10))
  pytest>=4.6,>=5.0,>=5.2 (from -r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 10))
  pytest-cov (from -r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 3))
  pytest-flask (from -r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 11))
  pytest-mock (from -r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 9))
  python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  pytz (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  pyyaml>=5.1 (from pre-commit==2.10.1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 2))
  regex>=2020.1.8 (from black==20.8b1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 5))
  requests>=2.0,>=2.5 (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  responses>=0.9.0 (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 (from boto3==1.17.19->moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  setuptools (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  six<2,>1.9,>=1.5,>=1.9.0 (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  sqlalchemy>=0.8.0 (from flask-sqlalchemy==2.4.4->pylint-flask-sqlalchemy==0.2.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 6))
  toml>=0.10.1,>=0.7.1 (from black==20.8b1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 5))
  typed-ast>=1.4.0 (from black==20.8b1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 5))
  typing-extensions>=3.7.4 (from black==20.8b1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 5))
  urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1,>=1.25.10,>=1.25.4 (from requests==2.25.1->moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  virtualenv>=20.0.8 (from pre-commit==2.10.1->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 2))
  werkzeug>=0.15,>=0.7 (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  wrapt<1.13,>=1.11 (from astroid==2.5.1->pylint==2.7.2->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 8))
  xmltodict (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))
  zipp (from moto==2.0.0->-r /var/folders/m1/ldn6fy6n38d52b1fmztr99br0000gp/T/pipenv_dzvh1okrequirements/pipenv-hiqg4rg0-constraints.txt (line 4))

Finding the best candidates:
  found candidate appdirs==1.4.4 (constraint was >=1.4.3,<2)
  found candidate astroid==2.5.1 (constraint was >=2.5.1,<2.6)
  found candidate atomicwrites==1.4.0 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate attrs==20.3.0 (constraint was >=19.2.0)
  found candidate autopep8==1.5.5 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate black==20.8b1 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate boto3==1.17.19 (constraint was >=1.9.201)
  found candidate botocore==1.20.19 (constraint was >=1.12.201,>=1.12.36,>=1.20.19,<1.21.0,<2.0a.0)
  found candidate certifi==2020.12.5 (constraint was >=2017.4.17)
  found candidate cffi==1.14.5 (constraint was >=1.12)
  found candidate cfgv==3.2.0 (constraint was >=2.0.0)
  found candidate chardet==4.0.0 (constraint was >=3.0.2,<5)
  found candidate click==7.1.2 (constraint was >=5.1,>=7.1.2)
  found candidate coverage==5.5 (constraint was >=5.2.1)
  found candidate cryptography==3.4.6 (constraint was >=3.3.1)
  found candidate distlib==0.3.1 (constraint was >=0.3.1,<1)
  found candidate filelock==3.0.12 (constraint was >=3.0.0,<4)
  found candidate flask==1.1.2 (constraint was >=0.10)
  found candidate flask-sqlalchemy==2.4.4 (constraint was >=2)
  found candidate identify==2.0.0 (constraint was >=1.0.0)
  found candidate idna==2.10 (constraint was >=2.5,<3)
  found candidate iniconfig==1.1.1 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate isort==5.7.0 (constraint was >=4.2.5,<6)
  found candidate itsdangerous==1.1.0 (constraint was >=0.24)
  found candidate jinja2==2.11.3 (constraint was >=2.10.1)
  found candidate jmespath==0.10.0 (constraint was >=0.7.1,<1.0.0)
  found candidate lazy-object-proxy==1.5.2 (constraint was >=1.4.0)
  found candidate markupsafe==1.1.1 (constraint was >=0.23,<2.0)
  found candidate mccabe==0.6.1 (constraint was >=0.6,<0.7)
  found candidate mock==4.0.3 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate more-itertools==8.7.0 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate moto==2.0.0 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate mypy-extensions==0.4.3 (constraint was >=0.4.3)
  found candidate nodeenv==1.5.0 (constraint was >=0.11.1)
  found candidate packaging==20.9 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate pathspec==0.8.1 (constraint was >=0.6,<1)
  found candidate pluggy==0.13.1 (constraint was >=0.12,<1.0.0a1)
  found candidate pre-commit==2.10.1 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate py==1.10.0 (constraint was >=1.8.2)
  found candidate pycodestyle==2.6.0 (constraint was >=2.6.0)
  found candidate pycparser==2.20 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate pylint==2.7.2 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate pylint-flask-sqlalchemy==0.2.0 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate pyparsing==2.4.7 (constraint was >=2.0.2)
  found candidate pytest==6.2.2 (constraint was >=4.6,>=5.0,>=5.2)
  found candidate pytest-cov==2.11.1 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate pytest-flask==1.2.0 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate pytest-mock==3.5.1 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate python-dateutil==2.8.1 (constraint was >=2.1,<3.0.0)
  found candidate pytz==2021.1 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate pyyaml==5.4.1 (constraint was >=5.1)
  found candidate regex==2020.11.13 (constraint was >=2020.1.8)
  found candidate requests==2.25.1 (constraint was >=2.0,>=2.5)
  found candidate responses==0.12.1 (constraint was >=0.9.0)
  found candidate s3transfer==0.3.4 (constraint was >=0.3.0,<0.4.0)
  found candidate setuptools==54.0.0 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate six==1.15.0 (constraint was >=1.5,>1.9,>=1.9.0,<2)
  found candidate sqlalchemy==1.3.23 (constraint was >=0.8.0)
  found candidate toml==0.10.2 (constraint was >=0.10.1,>=0.7.1)
  found candidate typed-ast==1.4.2 (constraint was >=1.4.0)
  found candidate typing-extensions==3.7.4.3 (constraint was >=3.7.4)
  found candidate urllib3==1.26.3 (constraint was >=1.21.1,>=1.25.10,>=1.25.4,<1.27)
  found candidate virtualenv==20.4.2 (constraint was >=20.0.8)
  found candidate werkzeug==1.0.1 (constraint was >=0.15,>=0.7)
  found candidate wrapt==1.12.1 (constraint was >=1.11,<1.13)
  found candidate xmltodict==0.12.0 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate zipp==3.4.0 (constraint was <any>)

Finding secondary dependencies:
  pycodestyle==2.6.0        requires -
  distlib==0.3.1            requires -
  pluggy==0.13.1            requires -
  requests==2.25.1          requires certifi>=2017.4.17, chardet<5,>=3.0.2, idna<3,>=2.5, urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  filelock==3.0.12          requires -
  xmltodict==0.12.0         requires -
  chardet==4.0.0            requires -
  markupsafe==1.1.1         requires -
  identify==2.0.0           requires -
  itsdangerous==1.1.0       requires -
  lazy-object-proxy==1.5.2  requires -
  setuptools==54.0.0        requires -
  more-itertools==8.7.0     requires -
  coverage==5.5             requires -
  pytest-mock==3.5.1        requires pytest>=5.0
  attrs==20.3.0             requires -
  pre-commit==2.10.1        requires cfgv>=2.0.0, identify>=1.0.0, nodeenv>=0.11.1, pyyaml>=5.1, toml, virtualenv>=20.0.8
  pathspec==0.8.1           requires -
  wrapt==1.12.1             requires -
  py==1.10.0                requires -
  cffi==1.14.5              requires pycparser
  astroid==2.5.1            requires lazy-object-proxy>=1.4.0, wrapt<1.13,>=1.11
  botocore==1.20.19         requires jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1, python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1, urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4
  flask-sqlalchemy==2.4.4   requires flask>=0.10, sqlalchemy>=0.8.0
  nodeenv==1.5.0            requires -
  pyparsing==2.4.7          requires -
  iniconfig==1.1.1          requires -
  responses==0.12.1         requires requests>=2.0, six, urllib3>=1.25.10
  mock==4.0.3               requires -
  click==7.1.2              requires -
  mypy-extensions==0.4.3    requires -
  pytest-flask==1.2.0       requires flask, pytest>=5.2, werkzeug>=0.7
  pytz==2021.1              requires -
  appdirs==1.4.4            requires -
  werkzeug==1.0.1           requires -
  boto3==1.17.19            requires botocore<1.21.0,>=1.20.19, jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1, s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0
  cfgv==3.2.0               requires -
  pycparser==2.20 not in cache, need to check index
  pycparser==2.20           requires -
  urllib3==1.26.3           requires -
  packaging==20.9           requires pyparsing>=2.0.2
  typing-extensions==3.7.4.3 requires -
  moto==2.0.0               requires boto3>=1.9.201, botocore>=1.12.201, cryptography>=3.3.1, jinja2>=2.10.1, markupsafe<2.0, mock, more-itertools, python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1, pytz, requests>=2.5, responses>=0.9.0, setuptools, six>1.9, werkzeug, xmltodict, zipp
  mccabe==0.6.1             requires -
  autopep8==1.5.5           requires pycodestyle>=2.6.0, toml
  pytest-cov==2.11.1        requires coverage>=5.2.1, pytest>=4.6
  black==20.8b1             requires appdirs, click>=7.1.2, mypy-extensions>=0.4.3, pathspec<1,>=0.6, regex>=2020.1.8, toml>=0.10.1, typed-ast>=1.4.0, typing-extensions>=3.7.4
  jmespath==0.10.0          requires -
  certifi==2020.12.5        requires -
  s3transfer==0.3.4         requires botocore<2.0a.0,>=1.12.36
  sqlalchemy==1.3.23        requires -
  isort==5.7.0              requires -
  typed-ast==1.4.2          requires -
  virtualenv==20.4.2        requires appdirs<2,>=1.4.3, distlib<1,>=0.3.1, filelock<4,>=3.0.0, six<2,>=1.9.0
  cryptography==3.4.6       requires cffi>=1.12
  six==1.15.0               requires -
  atomicwrites==1.4.0       requires -
  regex==2020.11.13         requires -
  jinja2==2.11.3            requires markupsafe>=0.23
  pyyaml==5.4.1             requires -
  flask==1.1.2              requires click>=5.1, itsdangerous>=0.24, jinja2>=2.10.1, werkzeug>=0.15
  pylint==2.7.2             requires astroid<2.6,>=2.5.1, isort<6,>=4.2.5, mccabe<0.7,>=0.6, toml>=0.7.1
  pylint-flask-sqlalchemy==0.2.0 requires flask-sqlalchemy>=2, pylint
  python-dateutil==2.8.1    requires six>=1.5
  zipp==3.4.0               requires -
  idna==2.10                requires -
  toml==0.10.2              requires -
  pytest==6.2.2             requires attrs>=19.2.0, iniconfig, packaging, pluggy<1.0.0a1,>=0.12, py>=1.8.2, toml
------------------------------------------------------------
Result of round 4: stable, done

Generating hashes:
  pycodestyle
  pluggy
  requests
  distlib
  filelock
  xmltodict
  chardet
  markupsafe
  identify
  itsdangerous
  lazy-object-proxy
  more-itertools
  coverage
  pytest-mock
  attrs
  pre-commit
  pathspec
  wrapt
  py
  cffi
  astroid
  botocore
  flask-sqlalchemy
  nodeenv
  pyparsing
  iniconfig
  responses
  mock
  click
  mypy-extensions
  pytest-flask
  pytz
  appdirs
  werkzeug
  boto3
  cfgv
  pycparser
  urllib3
  packaging
  typing-extensions
  moto
  mccabe
  autopep8
  pytest-cov
  black
  jmespath
  certifi
  s3transfer
  sqlalchemy
  isort
  typed-ast
  virtualenv
  cryptography
  six
  atomicwrites
  regex
  jinja2
  pyyaml
  flask
  pylint
  pylint-flask-sqlalchemy
  python-dateutil
  zipp
  idna
  toml
  pytest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 98, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1654, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1644, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1402, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3417, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1402, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3739, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1402, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3400, in parseImpl
    loc, resultlist = self.exprs[0]._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1406, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 2711, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:(abcd...) (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 807, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 802, in main
    _main(parsed.pre, parsed.clear, parsed.verbose, parsed.system, parsed.write,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 785, in _main
    resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 758, in resolve_packages
    results = clean_results(results, resolver, project)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 640, in clean_results
    entry_dict = translate_markers(entry.get_cleaned_dict(keep_outdated=False))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 239, in get_cleaned_dict
    self.validate_constraints()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 565, in validate_constraints
    constraints = self.get_constraints()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 493, in get_constraints
    pipfile_constraint = self.get_pipfile_constraint()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 507, in get_pipfile_constraint
    return self.constraint_from_parent_conflicts()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 524, in constraint_from_parent_conflicts
    if p.is_updated:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 604, in __getattribute__
    entry = Entry.__getattribute__(self, "entry")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 625, in __getattribute__
    return super(Entry, self).__getattribute__(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 279, in entry
    self._entry = self.make_requirement(self.name, self.entry_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 137, in make_requirement
    return Requirement.from_pipfile(name, entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 2743, in from_pipfile
    r = NamedRequirement.from_pipfile(name, pipfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 1382, in from_pipfile
    req = init_requirement("{0}{1}".format(name, version))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/utils.py", line 200, in init_requirement
    req = Requirement.parse(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3135, in parse
    req, = parse_requirements(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3080, in parse_requirements
    yield Requirement(line)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3090, in __init__
    super(Requirement, self).__init__(requirement_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 100, in __init__
    raise InvalidRequirement(
pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Parse error at "'-otocore'": Expected W:(abcd...)
```